# Passing Typescript "Map" in Angular4 and send by HTTP POST request

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to send part of object like `query:Map<String, List<String>>`  to java so I put as `queries!: Map<string, string[]>;` in interface
and in typescript

```
let x = this.searchName
    let y = this.searchValue
  const m = new Map<string, string[]>();
    this.SearchDto.queries = m.set(x, [y]);
 this._filterSer.searchAgg(this.SearchDto).subscribe((res) => {})
```

but in send to backend as {}

What's the error ?

Comment: try `const m = {[x]: [y]};` this is a way to define javascript object, and in the vast majority of libraries simple js object is used as a `Map` analogue

Comment: ok thanks alot but how to push new data in this const m = {[x]: [y]};?

Comment: `m[someField] = someValue;` or, if you have all the data before creating the object then just enumerate all the fields `const m = {[x]: [y], field2: 3, field3: 541234}`; just take a look at "computed properties" syntax to understand more, what are square brackets doing in these pieces of code